# Installing python module "Pygame" problem

Tags: python, bash, macos, pip, pygame

I've been trying to install pygame on Mac OS 15 but everytime I do

```
pip3 install pygame
```

I always get this error. I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong, near the end it also talks about gcc files and SDL.h. I don't understand at all.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-install-o1o9ggvd/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-install-o1o9ggvd/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-record-ugnejw2q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/bilalraja/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
     cwd: /private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-install-o1o9ggvd/pygame/
Complete output (218 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
running build_ext
building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o
In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------


ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-install-o1o9ggvd/pygame/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-install-o1o9ggvd/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/wn/2q0b4pf951d3lz81bvfgn8fh0000gn/T/pip-record-ugnejw2q/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/bilalraja/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I fix this? I've looked everywhere on the internet but can't find a single tutorial on this bug I need help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+%27SDL.h%27+file+not+found

Comment: ```python -m pip install pygame``` may work or ```python -m pip3 install pygame```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install development version of SDL. SDL is written in C (C++?) so it can not be install by python means, and python bindings require headers from it. I'm not sure about Macs, but try something like `brew install sdl2` (see https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sdl2).

Comment: how do i install brew